# How can I calculate the user Age based on a sql DATE datatype

Tags: javascript, sql, date

So from my SQL query I receive: FRI DEC 13 1991 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET) as a date result. But All I want is the current user age in years. Is there anyway to calculate this? Or is there any nom extension I can use? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Which database are you using? Is the column of date type?

Comment: @GurV It's a SQL database, type is date.

Comment: Do you have control over the query that returns you that date? Also, @GurV was asking whether you're using MySQL, Oracle, MS Sql...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day,'olddate','recentdate') AS AGE FROM your_table;
```

The returned value is AGE. Use whatever date format you have but that is the SQL query for your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Javascript Date object like this:

```
var sqlDate = new Date('FRI DEC 13 1991 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)');
//log year
console.log(sqlDate.getFullYear());
var intPersonYOB = sqlDate.getFullYear()
```

To do something with the `year`, you create a new `Date` object and get the current year as follows so you can do some maths with it:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();
var intPersonAge = currentYear - intPersonYOB;
console.log(intPersonAge);`
```

This should be enough the get his age

Answer (score 0):

Function bellow will return age by your string. You can use same approach.

```
ar str = 'FRI DEC 13 1991 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)';

age = getAge(str);

function getAge(str) {
  var matches = str.match(/[a-z]{3} ([a-z]{3}) (\d{1,2}) (\d{4})/i);
  str = matches[3] + '-';
  switch (matches[1]) {
    case 'JAN':
      str += '01-';
      break;
    case 'FEB':
      str += '02-';
      break;
    case 'MAR':
      str += '03-';
      break;
    case 'APR':
      str += '04-';
      break;
    case 'MAY':
      str += '05-';
      break;
    case 'JUN':
      str += '06-';
      break;
    case 'JUL':
      str += '07-';
      break;
    case 'AUG':
      str += '08-';
      break;
    case 'SEP':
      str += '09-';
      break;
    case 'OCT':
      str += '10-';
      break;
    case 'NOV':
      str += '11-';
      break;
    case 'DEC':
      str += '12-';
      break;
  }
  str += parseInt(matches[2]) < 10 ? '0' + matches[2] : matches[2];
  var birthDate = new Date(str);
  var nowDate = new Date();
  return nowDate.getFullYear() - 1 - birthDate.getFullYear() + (
      birthDate.getMonth() < nowDate.getMonth() ? 1 :
        birthDate.getMonth() == nowDate.getMonth() ? 
          birthDate.getDate() <= nowDate.getDate()   ? 1 : 0
        : 0  
    );
}
```